# Post OS X 10.10 Yosemite install Rails error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I did a clean install of Mac OS Yosemite, but now Rails won't work properly.

When I try to do `rails s` it tells me to do `bundle install`.

I get this message after trying to run `bundle install`:

```
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied - /Users/giowong/rails_project/doctible_pre_treatment/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bcrypt-3.1.7/.gitignore
```

I did

```
sudo gem update --system
```

and

```
bundle install
```

When I do this, I'm getting this nasty stuff:

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20141107-39214-1ds3j4x.rb extconf.rb 
checking for ruby/util.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
 need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--without-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir  
--ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:434:in      `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
  You have to install development tools first.
from          /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:549:in `block in try_compile'
from        /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:502:in `with_werror'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:549:in `try_compile'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:1044:in `block in have_header'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:895:in `block in checking_for'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:340:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:310:in `open'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:340:in `block in postpone'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:310:in `open'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:336:in `postpone'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:894:in `checking_for'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:1043:in `have_header'
from extconf.rb:14:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in      /Users/giowong/rails_project/doctible_pre_treatment/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bcrypt-3.1.7 for inspection.

 Results logged to     /Users/giowong/rails_project/doctible_pre_treatment/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/extensions/universal-darwin-14/2.0.0/bcrypt-3.1.7/gem_make.out
 An error occurred while installing bcrypt (3.1.7), and Bundler cannot continue.
 Make sure that `gem install bcrypt -v '3.1.7'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I've tried installing using

```
 \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails
```

but no luck.

Comment: When you install a gem using `sudo`, you are modifying the Apple-installed Ruby, so don't do that, leave it alone for the system to use. Instead, use a Ruby version manager like [RVM](http://rvm.io/rvm/install) or [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv). And, with either of those, NEVER use `sudo` when installing anything for a Ruby they manage otherwise you will cause major confusion. If you go with RVM, read the entire installation directions so you understand what you're supposed to do.

Answer (score 3):

I don't recommend using the default Ruby provided with OS X, so install RVM instead. You will also need to install the Xcode command line tools:

```
xcode-select --install # click install, not Get Xcode
```

Then verify if gcc is installed:

```
gcc --version
```

And only then run:

```
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails
```

Comment: [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) is a worthy alternative to RVM; It's not as heavyweight.